# jquery function to replace an abreviation by the full word

Tags: php, jquery, replace, textarea, ckeditor

I met some trouble with my jquery script.

Here is the code

```
<script>

 $(function()
{

    $('#suivi').keyup(function(e){
    var code = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var input = this.value;
    console.log(input);
          if (input == "ABS") {
       this.value = "Le débiteur est absent, nous le relançons par courrier. Nous agendons également une visite domiciliaire s'il s'avérait que ce dernier restait sans réponse."

    };

});

});



</script>
```

the trouble is that it replace an abreviation by the full word, for example tel would be replaced by telephone.  The trouble is that this code works if and only if, the textarea is empty, for example if I write and I quote: " give me the tel" without the quotes, it wont change the word, but if I write only tel, it works, I would like to do that I can add many abbreviations and not only at the beginning,

Is there a way I can do that?

Moreover I use often ckeditor, when the textarea is plugged in with Ckeditor, it will not work.

Is there a way I can change that?

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Kind regards.

SP.

Comment: How the heck are we suppose to know what your PHP code is outputting? On the other hand, you probably should'nt replace the entire value, but just use `string.replace()` or something similar to replace the words seperately.

Comment: ok, Actualy it just output an abrviation and its expression like that I've updated the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following that uses an object to map the acronym/abbreviation to the given phrase and, if the abbreviation is detected, replaces that abbreviation with the full phrase:

```
var abbreviations = {
    'PSI': 'pounds per square inch',
    'TLA': 'three-letter acronym'
};

function abbrReplace(el, abbrs) {
    if (!el || !abbrs) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var val = el.value,
            words = val.split(/\s/);
        for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i<len; i++) {
            if (abbrs[words[i]]) {
                words[i] = abbrs[words[i]];
            }
        }
        return words.join(' ');
    }
}
document.getElementById('test').onblur = function(){
    this.value = abbrReplace(this, abbreviations);
};
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UHG4z/).

This is, however, case-sensitive so, in the above, the abbreviation `tla` wouldn't be matched, only `TLA` would.

Comment: dear Sir, thanks for your quick reply. Actualy this works fine. The only trouble I have is that this do not work on CKEDITOR

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#suivi').on('keyup', function(e){
       var code = e.which; //normalized by jQuery
       if (this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf("abs")!=-1) {
           this.value = this.value.replace(/ABS/g, 'Anal Bitch Slapper');
       }
    });
});
```

Don't replace the entire value, replace the abbreviaton with whatever it stands for in the string, and you'll need a standard regex for global replace, the string replace above just replaces the first occurence.

Comment: regex would be better e.g. `this.value.match(/\babs\b/i)`

Comment: Actually, making it case-insensitiv is easily done by converting to lower case, and replacing globally is done with the g modifier (global). Modified my answer as well!